# Empty scrollbars on canvas page?

Tags: facebook, canvas, scrollbars

was just trying to set up a canvas page for our app. Got empty scrollbars. Tried with a URL that's working in another app to see if theres something wrong with my iframed page. Empty scrollbars again. What setting would I have to change? Professor Google only told me about deprecated options for canvas settings.

This is my canvas page showing scrollbars:
http://apps.facebook.com/canvasscrollbars/

This is the canvas page I copied the iframed page from - no scrollbars here!
http://apps.facebook.com/tabpress

EDIT: Problem as described in Firefox, IE shows only vertical scrollbar. Safari and Chrome working fine and showing no scrollbars as desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to "Advanced settings" of your Facebook app, then find "Canvas Settings" section and change "Canvas Height" to "Settable (Default: 800px)". 
In my case this fixed scrollbar problem.